# How to send thread::id to PostThreadMessageA?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, visual-c++

I have a `std::thread` object and i want to send thread id which is `std::thread::id` to [PostThreadMessageA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postthreadmessagea) which get a `DWORD` a `typedef` of `unsigned long`. How can i send thread id ?

Comment: You need GetThreadId((HANDLE)t.native_handle)

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you can call the function [`std::thread::native_handle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle) to obtain the implementation-defined native handle type and [`std::thread::get_id`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/get_id) to obtain the thread ID.

Since the function [`PostThreadMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postthreadmessagea) that you mentioned requires a thread ID and not a "handle", at first glance, it would appear meaningful to use the function `std::thread::get_id` instead of `std::thread::native_handle`. However, according to the [official Microsoft documentation for the function `std::thread::get_id`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/thread-class?view=vs-2019#get_id), the function returns an object of type `class thread::id` and not a `DWORD`, but the function `PostThreadMessage` requires a `DWORD` for the thread ID. The [official Microsoft documentation on `class thread::id`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/thread-class?view=vs-2019#id_class) does not provide any documented way to convert this class to a `DWORD`.

Although it may be possible to convert a `class thread::id` to a `DWORD` through some kind of undocumented hack, I recommend that you use the following documented approach instead:

According to the [official Microsoft documentation on the function `std::thread::native_handle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/thread-class?view=vs-2019#native_handle), the function returns a native Win32 `HANDLE`. This means that you can pass this `HANDLE` to native Win32 API functions. Therefore, you can pass such a `HANDLE` to the Win32 API function [`GetThreadId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getthreadid), which returns the thread ID as a `DWORD`. This returned value can then be passed to the function `PostThreadMessage`.

So, to extract the thread ID as a `DWORD` from an object of type `std::thread`, you can use the following line of code:

`DWORD dwThreadId = GetThreadId( my_thread_object.native_handle() );`

Please note that the function `PostThreadMessage` requires that the target thread has created a message queue, otherwise the function call will fail. If the thread was created through the `std::thread` API, it is possible that such a message queue was not created. Therefore, you should ensure that the target thread calls the function `GetMessage` or `PeekMessage` at least once before sending that thread a message using `PostThreadMessage`. See the [official Microsoft documentation on this function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postthreadmessagea) for further information.

Comment: "*If the thread was created through the std::thread API, it is unlikely that such a message queue was created.*" - Not unlikely if it's designed right.  If the target thread has invoked GetMessage or PeekMessage at least once, it's got a queue.

Comment: @selbie: Thanks, I have reformulated my answer accordingly.